# Replace [b]xxx[/b] with 'xxx' in bold

Tags: regex, vb.net, asp.net-3.5, string-formatting, bbcode

How can I convert `[b]xxx[/b]` to `<strong>xxx</strong>` using VB.NET Regex.Replace()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a [BBCode parser](http://bbcode.codeplex.com/) that someone else has written. It’s safer and more robust.

Comment: Why have I not come across this before! :O Thanks @jleedev!

Answer (score 6):

`Regex.Replace("\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]", "<strong>$1</strong>")` would do it

However, you don't need regex:

`"[b]xxx[/b]".Replace("[b]","<strong>").Replace("[/b]","</strong>")`

Comment: Not using Regex could cause problems if an end [/b] isn't entered. And considering this content will be managed by the public, I'm sure they will forget :)